# Como suavizar uma curva no R

Tags: r, ggplot2

O objetivo é obter o gráfico suavizado do [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame)

```r
x <- c(1e-04, 0.0014,  0.018, 0.24, 3.2, 42, 560, 7500, 1e+05)
y <- c(0, 7, 10, 7, 0, -7, -10, -7, 0)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

A curva gerada por

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + scale_x_log10() + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ficou ligada por retas. Como fazer uma curva mais suave com o [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2)?

Comment: Muito reticulada? O gráfico está apenas plotando os pontos, ligando por linhas. Se você quer encaixar uma curva nos pontos que você tem, você talvez queira fazer uma regressão polinomial para esse caso -- seria isso que você está buscando?

Comment: Usei o termo reticulada para expressar os pontos ligados por linhas. Vou consertar. Acho que a regressão polinomial pode resolver o problema. Mas, como eu gostaria que a curva passasse por todos os pontos, a ordem do polinômio tem que ser igual ao número de pontos, certo? Com 9 pontos acho que funciona, o meu caso real tem 50 pontos. Vou tentar a sua solução.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É melhor interpolar os pontos usando splines:

```r
sp <- data.frame(spline(log10(df$x), df$y, n = 8*nrow(df)))
sp$x <- 10 ** sp$x
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + scale_x_log10() + geom_point() + geom_line(data=sp)
```

O número 8 representa a quantidade de pontos criados para cada ponto original (contando o próprio ponto original); quanto maior esse número, mais suave é a curva.

Como seu gráfico possui uma escala logarítmica em x, foi necessário tirar o logaritmos dos valores de x antes de interpolar os pontos, para garantir que a função criará pontos equidistantes no eixo x do gráfico.

[image: gráfico com splines]

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra forma bem rápida de ajustar uma linha suavizada é usar o próprio `geom_smooth` do `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + scale_x_log10() + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Update**: Seguindo o comentário do Marcos, fazendo a linha de ajuste passar pelos pontos com um polinômio:

```
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + scale_x_log10() + geom_point() + 
     geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = y ~ poly(x, nrow(df) - 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O objetivo é que a curva passe sobre os pontos. Usando a sua sugestão consegui com `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = y ~ poly(x, nrow(df) - 1))`

Comment: Ah, me desculpe, Marcos! Não percebi que era para passar pelos pontos! Vou atualizar a resposta com sua sugestão!