# Como suavizar esse gráfico no R/Rstudio?

Tags: r

Se eu plotar o gráfico normalmente

```
pontos.x = c(7.522936, 12.228712, 17.316037, 22.148996, 27.236321, 32.196464, 37.283789, 
42.116748, 47.076890, 52.164215, 57.378723, 62.211682, 67.426190)

pontos.y = c(0.001583012, 0.001583012, 0.013938224, 0.017799228, 0.034015444, 
0.032374517, 0.037876448, 0.023880309, 0.017799228, 0.010849421, 0.003030888, 
0.003899614, 0.001583012)

plot(pontos.x, pontos.y, type = "l")
```

ele plota normalmente, mas a curva fica reta (?). Se alguém puder ajudar, queria que os pontos fossem ligados mas por curvas e não por retas, como se fosse um smooth, já pesquisei a respeito mas nenhuma solução, pois preciso fazer um histograma e passar uma curva com esses pontos em cima dele (add = T).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como suavizar uma curva no R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7956/como-suavizar-uma-curva-no-r)

Comment: Rafael, você já olhou as respostas da pergunta acima?

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira de fazer esta suavização é, em primeiro lugar, escolher uma ferramenta capaz de gerar a curva que vai interpolar os teus dados. Minha sugestão é fazer uma regressão loess de `pontos.y` em `pontos.x` e plotar estes dados em cima do histograma através da função `lines`:

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean=37.5, sd=10)
hist(x, prob=TRUE)
ajuste <- loess(pontos.y ~ pontos.x)
lines(pontos.x, predict(ajuste))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a curva sobreposta não ficou ideal, sugiro encontrar os melhores valores para os argumentos `span` e `degree` da função `loess`.

Outra maneira de fazer este é utilizar a função `density`, onde ela própria é um estimador da função densidade dos teus dados. Particularmente, é a minha solução preferida:

```
hist(x, prob=TRUE)
lines(density(x))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma terceira maneira é utilizar o pacote `ggplot2` para fazer o histograma e estimar simultaneamente a função densidade dos dados da amostra:

```
dados <- data.frame(x=x)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dados, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..)) +
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="white")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, Marcus.